# Excel Number Separation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Need help on make excel number format to a list of numbers.
For example:

> 1-3

to become below on different rows.

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

If anyone could help

Comment: You need to do it in excel-vba. we can help you if you will have problem after starting - but we will not write it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with a formula only:

We assume that A1=`1-3`. Fill the following formula into A2 and copy it down.

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(ISNUMBER(A1),IF(A1+1<=VALUE(RIGHT(A$1,LEN(A$1)-FIND("-",A$1))),A1+1,""),VALUE(LEFT(A$1,FIND("-",A$1)-1))),"")
```

The result will be

```
1
2
3
```

This works for any numbers devided by `-`.

Comment: this one works! thank you